# Python, OpenCV - drawContours of overlapping regions, some pixels are excluded?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-editing

I am experimenting with cv2.drawContours. I tried this:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np


def fix_format(cts):
    return [np.asarray(np.round(ct), np.int32)[:, :, np.newaxis] for ct in cts]

# these are 2 overlapping rectangular regions
cts1 = [
    [[1, 1], [6, 1], [6, 4], [1,4]],
    [[3, 2], [7, 2], [7, 7], [3,7]]
             ]
img1 = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros([10, 10]), fix_format(cts1), contourIdx=-1, color=1, thickness=-1)
```

I assumed that, since I am using `thickness=-1`, contours would be filled, and since the areas are overlapping I would end up with the union of the areas delimited by the 2 contours in `cts1`.
However, when printing `img1`, I see there are 2 values that are still 0 in the overlapping area (img1[3][4] and img1[3][5]).
Why is this happening?

EDIT:

I tried using the 2 contours separately, and this is what I get (for the first, second and both contours, respectively):

[image: cnt1]
[image: cnt2]
[image: both]

Comment: My guess is the note in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc): "This may give incorrect results if you have a joint collection of separately retrieved contours. In order to solve this problem, you need to call drawContours separately for each sub-group of contours, or iterate over the collection using contourIdx parameter." What happens when you try to draw the contours independently?

Comment: have you tried with thickness=cv2.FILLED

Comment: @pippo1980 That's what the magic number `-1` corresponds to.

Comment: Anyway, what @beaker said is going to be the case. Your two polygons overlap. Distinct overlapping contours don't really make sense. I would have a look at [`fillPoly`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga311160e71d37e3b795324d097cb3a7dc), that seems more like what you want to do anyway.

Comment: @DanMašek , I just realized that the contours provided by OP are not contours a all , they are just a couple of four rectangle vertices , am I wrong ? a contour should be a string/list/array of  each single point defyning it (a bounduary , a fence , whathever ) shouldn't it ? quote : "Contours can be explained simply as a curve joining all the continuous points (along the boundary), having same color or intensity. The contours are a useful tool for shape analysis and object detection and recognition. " https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Comment: @pippo1980 There's a bit of overlap between polygons and contours in the way OpenCV treats those. Both are lists of 2d coordinates. When you use a [contour approximation mode](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga4303f45752694956374734a03c54d5ff) in `findContours` on a perfect rectangle, you ought to get just the four corner points, so in isolation, those would be valid contours. | However, there is no possible scenario, where `findContours` could return a result like OP's example input (where the polygons intersect).

Comment: I see CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE 
Python: cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
compresses horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leaves only their end points. For example, an up-right rectangular contour is encoded with 4 points.

Comment: @beaker see my attempt as an answer , I tried to provide real contours and not CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE , seems to wotk in my case, but not sure all the code is right

Comment: contours never overlap. drawContours assumes this. if your polygons overlap, you are using the wrong drawing function. that's all. -- also, opencv sucks at being careful about pixel-exact drawing. those functions, functionally, are two decades old.

Answer (score 0):

mmmh I tried to figure out what is going on and tried some more on the same example , please follow this approach:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np


print('OpenCV version : ' , cv2.__version__)


def ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if width is None and height is None:
        return image
    if width is None:
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    else:
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)


draw_windows = True  ## change fo False for no windows only calc


def drawWindow(window_name, image):
    if draw_windows:
        
        resize = ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width= 500)
        
        cv2.imshow(window_name, resize)
        
        cv2.moveWindow(window_name, 600, 200)
        
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    pass

def fix_format(cts):
    return [np.asarray(np.round(ct), np.int32)[:, :, np.newaxis] for ct in cts]



# these are 2 overlapping rectangular regions
cts1 = [
    [[1, 1], [6, 1], [6, 4], [1,4]],
    [[3, 2], [7, 2], [7, 7], [3,7]]
                ]


img1 = np.zeros((10,10))

xmin = np.min(fix_format(cts1)[0][:,0])

xmax = np.max(fix_format(cts1)[0][:,0])

ymin = np.min(fix_format(cts1)[0][:,1])

ymax = np.max(fix_format(cts1)[0][:,1])

print(xmin, xmax, ymin , ymax)


imga = img1.copy().astype(np.uint8)


imga[ymin:ymax , xmin:xmax] = 1


cnt_a, hier = cv2.findContours(imga, cv2.RETR_LIST  , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE )



print(cnt_a[0].shape)


# img1 = cv2.drawContours(img1, cnt_a, contourIdx = -1 , color = 1, thickness = cv2.FILLED)


drawWindow('imga', imga*255)


# drawWindow('img1', img1)


xmin = np.min(fix_format(cts1)[1][:,0])

xmax = np.max(fix_format(cts1)[1][:,0])

ymin = np.min(fix_format(cts1)[1][:,1])

ymax = np.max(fix_format(cts1)[1][:,1])

print(xmin, xmax, ymin , ymax)


imgb = img1.copy().astype(np.uint8)


imgb[ymin:ymax , xmin:xmax] = 1


cnt_b, hier = cv2.findContours(imgb, cv2.RETR_LIST  , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE )



print(cnt_b[0].shape)

drawWindow('imgb', imgb*255)


img1 = cv2.drawContours(img1, cnt_a, contourIdx = -1 , color = 1, thickness = cv2.FILLED)


img1 = cv2.drawContours(img1, cnt_b, contourIdx = -1 , color = 1, thickness = cv2.FILLED)


drawWindow('img1', img1)


print(cnt_a, cnt_a[0].shape)

print(cnt_b, cnt_b[0].shape)


cnt_ab = np.concatenate((cnt_a , cnt_b), axis=1)


print(cnt_ab , cnt_ab.shape)



imgx = cv2.drawContours(np.zeros([10, 10]), cnt_ab, contourIdx =-1 , color=1, thickness = cv2.FILLED)


drawWindow('imgx', imgx)
```

output:

**img1** :

[image]

**imga** :

[image]

**imgb** :

[image]

**img1** :

[image]

**imgX** :

[image]

changing :

`cnt_a, hier = cv2.findContours(imga, cv2.RETR_LIST  , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE )`

and

`cnt_b, hier = cv2.findContours(imgb, cv2.RETR_LIST  , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE )`

to

`cnt_a, hier = cv2.findContours(imga, cv2.RETR_LIST  , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )`

and

`cnt_b, hier = cv2.findContours(imgb, cv2.RETR_LIST  , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )`

I get **imgX** :

[image]

Comment: is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: Just to elaborate more on the difference between  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE and  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE    not sure but the two results could have different shapes too. I was waiting for you to jump in bringing some wisdom , as always I would truly appreciate that, if you have time to spare. Greetings Pippo